# Capture text between two strings

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to capture a string that is in a text field and between two other strings.

- Start string: {"website":"
- End string:   ","referrer":"

The complete string would look something like this:

- {"website":"www.Domain.com","referrer":"invited on google+"}
- Or:
- {"website":"www.AnotherDomain.com","referrer":""}
- Or perhaps:
- {"website":"www.about.me/SubDomain","referrer":""}

I simply need to capture everything between the start and end string and have been trying with various string methods with mixed results.

The start and end string would always be the same.

Any suggestions...?

Comment: [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @michi: simple explode can do that...

Comment: Parsing our own json would be a cool challenged but since you are using PHP I'd suggest using a built in function, unless you really don't want too. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: is that a json array? in that case json_decode it than return_array['website']

Comment: @akam yes, you're right about `explode`

Comment: preg match, string in string and now json I guess.

I'll have to give that a try...

Answer (score 4):

That is called a json array and it can be converted in a php array with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function.

```
$json = '{"website":"www.Domain.com","referrer":"invited on google+"}';
$info_array = json_decode($json, true);
echo $info_array['website'];
```

you will not need any preg_match, string split or other stuff.

Demo: http://codepad.org/Mz0iNcGo

Comment: I get the following error when I try that:

 - Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/

Comment: @Harlequin try with json_decode($json, true);

Comment: That's what I did though, I used the code above and what you are suggesting is identical, no...?

Comment: @Harlequin i added a second parameter 'true' ;)

Comment: @Harlequin added a demo as well: http://codepad.org/Mz0iNcGo

Comment: @Harlequin it would be nice to give me the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work...

```
<?php
$subject = "{"website":"www.Domain.com","referrer":"invited on google+"}";
$pattern = '/(?<=website":").*(?=","referrer)/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
?>
```

$matches[0] actually contains your string.